# Process/Mind mapping examples with Javascript?

Tags: visualization, raphael, processing, mindmapping

Are there any examples to create a process-Map or Mind-Mapping style visualizations using Javascript visualization libraries (eg: Raphael/Processing etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this! http://kenneth.kufluk.com/google/js-mindmap/
also simile widgets framework from MIT is also very useful.
http://www.simile-widgets.org/

Comment: Take a look also at this library: https://github.com/mindmup/mapjs . They open-sourced it quite recently.

Answer (score 0):

I created a mind map application using Raphael but it's still very buggy and so not released yet. Also Raphael version 2.0 will be released shortly and I will be rebuilding for that version.

There is a HTML5 version of mind mapping called [Think](http://think-app.appspot.com/)